# $[A\otimes C,B\otimes D]=0$ but neither $[A,B]= 0$ nor $[C,D]=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, $E\otimes E$ be the Hilbert space tensor product.

> I want to find $A,B,C,D\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ such that
>
> $[A\otimes C,B\otimes D]=0$ but neither $[A,B]= 0$ nor $[C,D]=0$.

Note that $[A\otimes C,B\otimes D]=0$ implies that
$$AB\otimes CD=BA\otimes DC.$$
By using the following result:

> **Lemma:** Let $A_1, A_2,B_1, B_2\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ be non-zero operators. The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> - $A_1\otimes B_1=A_2\otimes B_2$.
> - There exists $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$  such that $A_1 =zA_2$ and $B_1= z^{-1}B_2$.

By this lemma, we deduce the existence of $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $AB=zBA$ and $CD=z^{-1}DC$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need operators $A,B$ with $AB\ne BA$, but $AB=zBA$ for some $z\ne1$. One way to get this is to get a unitary with powers of a matrix unit in the diagonal, like 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix} -1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
and $A$ the unitary that permutes the diagonal, namely 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then 
$$
AB=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\ -1&0\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
while
$$
BA=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix} . 
$$
That is, $AB=-BA$. For these two matrices, 
$$
[A\otimes A,B\otimes B]=AB\otimes AB-BA\otimes BA=AB\otimes AB-AB\otimes AB=0, 
$$
but 
$$
[A,B]=AB-BA=2AB\ne0. 
$$